# read pdf document properties from terminal as seen in nautilus

Tags: shell, ubuntu, terminal, nautilus

From the terminal I would like to be access the data that is readable when right clicking on a pdf file and selecting "document".

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvflN.png) :[image: example]

I have tried reading metadata with tools such as mminfo and pdftk but some files are password protected so they can't show me the meta data.

Help appreciated.

Comment: And nautilus shows you these infos, no matter whether the files are password protected, or how do those 2 themes - nautilus and password - fit together?

Comment: [crossposting to AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/139957/read-pdf-document-properties-from-terminal-as-seen-in-nautilus)

Comment: indeed it does, even if password protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pdfinfo reveals following information for me:

```
pdfinfo XY.pdf 
Title:          XY Zufriedenheitsbefragung XY: 2012/5
Producer:       Apache FOP Version SVN branches/fop-0_95
CreationDate:   Fri May 18 13:38:45 2012
Tagged:         no
Pages:          8
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595 x 842 pts (A4)
File size:      33666 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4
```

but I don't know how it works on encrypted PDFs. But if nautilus can read them - why shouldn't a command line tool?

When I look for pdfinfo, I get 2 alternative answers:

```
apt-cache search pdfinfo
poppler-utils - PDF-Werkzeuge (basierend auf libpoppler)
xpdf-utils - Portable Document Format (PDF) suite -- utilities
```